# Will Postgres CTE read all rows even if it doesn't have to?

Tags: postgresql

Will a query like this read all rows from `big_table` or just the actually needed rows?

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT * FROM big_table)
SELECT * FROM
    small_table st
JOIN tmp ON tmp.Id = st.BigTableId
WHERE st.Id = 45
```

Would a sub select perform better?

```
SELECT * FROM
    small_table st
JOIN (SELECT * FROM big_table) as tmp ON tmp.Id = st.BigTableId
WHERE st.Id = 45
```

I like that it's possible to write a bit more readable queries using `WITH`, but not if the cost is worse performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query in CTE is executed autonomically (without any conditions from consecutive queries) In the case described in the question the query with CTE will be much slower than the other one.

Use EXPLAIN ANALYSE in cases you are in doubt. You should get plans similar to the following.

With CTE (the big table has 100000 rows, all of them will be scanned in cte):

```
 Hash Join  (cost=1580.96..4269.53 rows=565 width=12) (actual time=10.349..42.718 rows=1 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (tmp.id = st.bigtableid)
   CTE tmp
     ->  Seq Scan on big_table  (cost=0.00..1572.65 rows=112965 width=4) (actual time=0.011..11.813 rows=100000 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on tmp  (cost=0.00..2259.30 rows=112965 width=4) (actual time=0.013..33.524 rows=100000 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=8.30..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
         ->  Index Scan using small_table_pkey on small_table st  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (id = 45)
```

Without CTE:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..16.61 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.069..0.071 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using small_table_pkey on small_table st  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = 45)
   ->  Index Only Scan using big_table_pkey on big_table  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.056..0.056 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = st.bigtableid)
         Heap Fetches: 1
```

Note that you do not need a subquery in the second query. It will be automatically optimized to this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM small_table st
JOIN big_table as tmp ON tmp.Id = st.BigTableId
WHERE st.Id = 45
```